# OSMDroid Showing multiple maps and infinite scroll

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

View of the application made using OSMdroid:
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/wiki/How-to-use-the-osmdroid-library

Comment: The zoom level is the problem. Your app can set a suitable start zoom level and also restrictions for the user.

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thank you for replying

Answer (score 5):

Find out myself.

```
    map.setHorizontalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);
    map.setVerticalMapRepetitionEnabled(false);

    map.setScrollableAreaLimitLatitude(MapView.getTileSystem().getMaxLatitude(), MapView.getTileSystem().getMinLatitude(), 0);
```